# How to change caption size in org-mode export to HTML

Tags: org-mode, html

Say I have the following figure:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :title This Figure
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 50%
#+CAPTION: blah blah blah.
[[./figure.png]]
```

The resulting caption in the .html (generated from `org-html-export-to-html`) file looks like this:

```
<p><span class="figure-number">Figure 1: </span>blah blah blah.</p>
```

How can I make the caption smaller? I tried to enclose the caption text in `<p size="3">blah blah blah</p>` but that prints what I typed literally.

Font tags are no longer supported in HTML5 so not sure what else to try here.

Comment: Use CSS. You should be able to use the `figure-number` class and set the font size for that.

Comment: Since only Figure1 is included in the span of `figure-number`, it doesn't affect the main text?

Comment: Right: you might be able to define the caption with a  `<span class=...>` around it and see if it is exported properly, but it would be HTML-specific (although you could use macros to abstract that).

Comment: Hm, seemed like a good idea but `<span font-size="50%"> blah </span>` did not work